# loading a class from a parent namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, zend-framework2, phpunit, autoload

i'm working on an application in a modular way, that is, i have a interface and i want to make an unit test for all the classes that implement that interface so i made an abstract class that  have all the logic implemented(testing if the class is actually implementing the interface, testing the return values and so on) but when i try to inherit the abstract class i get an `class not found exception` i'm working with namespaces so my directory structure is like this

```
namespaceA
|->abstract.php
|->namespaceB
    |->pluginTest.php
```

so my pluginTest.php class definition is like this

```
namespace namespaceA\namespaceB;    
use namespaceA\Abstract;

class pluginTest extends Abstract
```

and obviously in my abstract class there is the namespaceA definition, i have also tried to manually include the file (`include("../Abstract.php")`) but it failed, but since i have used autoloading for a while maybe i don't remember well how to manually import, i also have tried with alias of the class (`using namespaceA\Abstract as X`) and by putting an `\` before the namespaceA but nothing work, what im doing wrong, or what im missing

**==edit==**

i managed to load the class using

```
include __DIR__ ."/../Abstract.php";
```

but still not autoloading

Comment: you do not need to import it, always use autoloading

Comment: In your phpunit.xml you can specify bootstrap file location, setup all the autoloading there. for example https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/tests/phpunit.xml and https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/tests/bootstrap.php

Comment: @Xerkus i know, i just tried to see if it can load, and also i did the bootstraping using the documentantion of zend in this page http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html but still nothing

Comment: Try renaming your abstract.php to Abstract.php. autoloading using psr0 is case sensitive

Comment: well the real clas names are `testAbstract` (`testAbstract.php`) and `pluginTest` (`pluginTest.php`), an infact autoloading is working whit another namespaces,(pluginTest loads an class from an other namespace), but it dont work whit the parent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it i just have to add the test directory to the module.php like this

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    'namespaceA' => __DIR__ . '/test/' .'namespaceA', //added this line
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
```